# Excel File Upload in MVC Using Ajax request

Tags: asp.net, excel, ajax, model-view-controller

I am trying to upload an Excel file using an Ajax request.

**Here is my code :**

```
$.ajax({
                            url: "/Configuration/ImportCPTMappingWithApptType",
                            type: "POST",
                            contentType: false,
                            processData: false,
                            data: data1,
                            success: function (Message) {
                                Console.log(Message);
                                //$("#Products").html(Message);
                            },
                            failure: function (response) {
                                fnClosePageLoader();
                                fnErrormsg(response.responseText);
                            },
                            error: function (xhr, status, p3, p4) {
                                var err = "Error " + " " + status + " " + p3 + " " + p4;
                                if (xhr.responseText && xhr.responseText[0] == "{")
                                    err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).Message;
                                fnErrormsg(err);
                                alert(err);
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
```

But it throws an error 404 Not Found. What could be the problem?

Comment: Same ajax is working fine with HttpGet.

Answer (score 0):

It's not finding a controller named "Configuration" with a method of "ImportCPTMappingWithApptType", which has an attribute of [HttpPost]

You need to check your routes to find what the correct name to the method is.

An oldie but goodie helper is RouteDebugger
https://www.nuget.org/packages/routedebugger

Which when you run on your dev machine, will give you details on all your routes in your project and which ones (if any) match the path.